# Sending html to Javascript from PHP via JSON obejct

Tags: php, json

I'm sending some data from php through ajax to jquery.

If `$content="ABC";` everything is OK. I get alert with ABC.

If `$content="<div>ABC</div>";` then Houston has a problem. Nothing happens at all.

Here is PHP code

```
$json = json_encode(array("content" => $content));
echo $json;
```

And this is Jquery

```
 $('#'+pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number).ajaxSubmit({
 success: function(responseimage){
 result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage);
 alert(result.content);
```

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE!**
I've removed `jQuery.parseJSON`
so that line has only this code

`result = responseimage;`

And now I get the result in alert.
The result is the following

```
{"content":".<div>ABC&lt;\/div&gt;."}</div>
```

So we can see that JSON is not created well. I;ve tried  utf8_encode and trim , but they do nothing to the result. result is strange.

Comment: Wrapping html in json is [almost always] plain wrong. Send raw data, and style it via client-side templating.

Comment: I'm sending multiple data from PHP. That's why I need JSON, I've wrote only part of the code that's why you see only one JSON object

Comment: Yeah, I am just advising you to send raw data [text, strings, numerals], then to create DOM stuff in the browser. In case you are dealing with *meta* HTML [e.g. snippets of code like in Gist], it makes sense to send html code, but properly escaped as well.

Comment: What is the json you get in your javascript ?

Comment: @moonwave99 I understand you, but building html elements with javascript will be pain in .... for me :) maybe there is another way to do it the way I wanted?

Comment: @sub_stantial I get nothing in that way. I mean there is no alert at all

Comment: I mean what you get in the variable 'responseimage' ?

Comment: @sub_stantial nothing, alert fails to act, that means javascript fails

Comment: @david: of course you won't be creating DOM chunks with jQuery, but you'll be picking [something among these](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Comment: @moonwave99 I understand your approach but I think it's better to send html with form , pictures, text, buttons in it using php to construct and then JSON to deliver it to jquery. Your approach will work but I want to solve this equation somehow else.

Comment: Then just don't wrap it into json, it's pointless and unnecessary slow.

Comment: Then your json_encode must have failed. You can debug '$json' variable and check whether you get your desired json.

Comment: @moonwave99 I have several different objects which I must pass to jquery from php via ajax. The only instrument to pass several object I know is JSON object. If there is another object tell me please. Also I repeat I must pass those objects in shift.

Comment: @sub_stantial I understand that it fails. That's why I ask what's wrong cause I pass only this > "<div>ABC</div>"

Comment: @sub_stantial tried to make this way > <div>ABC<\/div>. result is the same. nothing happened. I understand that JSON does not likes HTML elements, so I'm interesting how to put it into json anyway

Comment: Just check the body of your http response, either by console.log-ing `responseimage` or by inspecting the Net panel in your browser's dev tools, because `echo json_encode('<sometag>Hello</sometag>)` works fine of course.

Comment: utf8_encode should be your solution. :)

Comment: @moonwave99 SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: @sub_stantial please write line of code where shoud I place it

Answer (score 0):

PHP (and JSON) code seems fine, provided that the variable $content actually has any content. Else the PHP script will fail and there's your problem.

Did you define the **dataType** as "json" in the AJAX request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not use $.ajax, instead of that I'm sending the whole form using jquery_form plugin. I've updated th first post so you could see the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to `utf8_encode` your response before doing `json_encode`.
Just change this :

```
$content = utf8_encode("<div>ABC</div>");
```

Comment: no luck. Again error > SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: Can u try `die( $json )` instead of `echo $json` in your php code ?

Comment: I've tried but no luck. The same error > SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: Also I'm googling this error and here is what I've found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972110/error-with-json-in-javascript-unexpected-non-whitespace-character-after-json-d  by the I use dreaviewer but The answer in that link is a bit complicated for me.

Comment: did you try trimming the `$json` using `trim($json)` before doing `echo` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are delivering invalid json somehow - please put your raw response in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), it will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Parse error on line 1:
<div>ABC</div>
^
Expecting '{', '['

Now what does that mean ?????

Comment: By raw response I intend the echo of `json_encode(array("content" => $content));`, not just the html of course.

Comment: I have no info about what will come from that echo cause script fails to perform on my server. So what I can put there ? I have no result to test

Comment: I thout it kinda php tester and put there php lines but it does not works

Comment: Frankly speaking, I really advise you to find a nice resource about how web works, and learn it from scratch: just patching a bad designed script with no clue about formats and standards won't help you at all.

Comment: Well that's why I'm here trying to understand my problem. I'm also googling the net for the answers. For now it's a bit difficult to get it. As I see you are in the same problem. That's why we are here, trying to get solution together sharing our thoughts.